# How to find the Primary address

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has Entities and these Entities can have multiple addresses.  The Addresses have a date added column also.  I would like to return all the address rows for a given entity and mark the Latest added Address as the Primary row and mark the rest of the returned rows as Not Primary.

This is what I am working with

```
select
A.ADDRESS_KEY
||','||
 e.PERSON_COMPANY_FLAG 
 ||','|| 
 e.ENTITY_KEY 
 ||','||
 Decode(a.ADDRESS_TYPE_KEY, '1', 'ADDR_OFFI', '2', 'ADDR_HOME', '3', 'ADDR_POBO', '4', 'ADDR_BUSI', '2212779', 'ADDR_TENN', '2212780', 'ADDR_OTHE', '2212781', 'ADDR_PYMT')
 ||','||
 a.date_added
 IS THIS THE PRIMARY ADDRESS Y OR N
  ||','||
  A.STREET
  --REPLACE(REPLACE(a.street, CHR(10), '  '), CHR(13), '  ')
  ||','||
  a.city
  ||','||
  rtrim(a.zip_code)
  ||','||
  a.state
  ||','||
  a.country
from
    oclp000.entity e
    join oclp000.address a on e.ENTITY_KEY = a.ENTITY_KEY
    join oclp000.addresstype at on a.ADDRESS_TYPE_KEY = at.ADDRESS_TYPE_KEY
where
  e.person_company_flag = 'C' 
  and e.entity_key = 5019139
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to determine which row is the last one added by sorting by the `date_added` in `DESC` order.    The first one will be primary.

```
SELECT 
  ... everything else ...
  , CASE 
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY e.entity_key ORDER BY a.date_added DESC ) = 1 
       THEN 'Y' 
       ELSE 'N' END is_primary_address
FROM ... what you already had ...
WHERE ... what you already had ...
```

#### UPDATE: String concatenation

To use this in a concatenated string, use `||` and omit the comma and the column alias ("is_primary_address") from the SQL above.  Like this:

```
SELECT 
  ... other parts of string ... || ',' ||
  CASE 
       WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY e.entity_key ORDER BY a.date_added DESC ) = 1 
       THEN 'Y' 
       ELSE 'N' END || ',' ||
  ... other parts of string ...
FROM ... what you already had ...
WHERE ... what you already had ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this..  One other twist this works if that is the last value in the string I am creating.  Is there a way to do something like this if this is in the middle of the string?

Comment: Just concatenate it in with `||`.  E.g., `other_stuff || CASE ... END || more_other_stuff`.

Comment: Using the || (concatenation) returns an error of FROM keyword not found where expected.  You have to use a comma after it and creates another column.